# Files processed more than once while using File System Watcher

Tags: c#, .net, timer, concurrency, filesystemwatcher

Im using file system watcher to watch a directory and process files as new ones are created.Im using a timer with background worker to prevent concurrency issues and memory overflow.

This is what i have

```
 //creating the watcher 

            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\watch";
             watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(copied);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;



//hooking to creation event

 void copied(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bwork.IsBusy == false)
            {
                bworkprocesslist.Add(e.FullPath);

            }
            else
            {
                bworkpendinglist.Add(e.FullPath);

            }


          }

  //used timer to prevent concurrent access of resources and memory overflow

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bwork.IsBusy==false)
            {
                bwork.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

        }


// Maintaining Lists and removed processed file from the main list 

 private void bwork_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> removedfiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string pfile in bworkprocesslist)
            {
            process(pfile) //Do processing of pfile
            removedfiles.Add(pfile);
            }
       foreach (string x in removedfiles)
        {

            bworkprocesslist.Remove(x);
        }


        }

//Add files from pending list after background worker completion



 void bwork_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in bworkpendinglist)
            {
                bworkprocesslist.Add(s);
                bworkpendinglist.Remove(s);
            }
        }
```

The code works without any issues.But it sometimes processes a file more than once.I cannot figure where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't looks like there is some error here.

From [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Common file system operations might raise **more than one event**. For
>   example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several
>   OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised.
>   Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple
>   operations, therefore raising multiple events.

Comment: So are you suggesting to throw away this feature in my program?

Comment: It depends on your program. :) If monitoring of flies is core feature - then obviously you can't throw it away. But since this event can be raised multiple times for a single file - you have to handle it somehow. Probably you have to check if this file was already added into processing list, or maybe check was it already processed or something like this. It's hard to suggest more outside of your application context.

Comment: Its not the core feature,buts its one of the feature.Even if the file gets processed twice there is no harm done as it will get replaced.But to prevent wasted resources and CPU Cycles i will check if the file has already been added to the list :)

Comment: Please see the answer below.I had made the change the person had suggested,but does not work.Hope he is right

Answer (score 0):

It seems like inside **bwork_RunWorkerCompleted** you are taking entries from your **bworkpendinglist** and adding them to your **bworkprocesslist**, but there's nowhere in the code I can see that you're removing from the **bworkpendinglist**.

i.e. Once you've added them to your **bworkprocesslist** you should remove them from the **bworkpendinglist**.

Comment: Please see the update.Added     bworkpendinglist.Remove(s);

Comment: Does this fix the problems you're seeing?

Comment: No same issue again.